# Recursively iterate through a nested dict and return value of the first matching key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I have a deeply nested dict and need to iterate through it and return the value corresponding to the `key` argument, second argument of my function.

For example, with

```
tree = {"a": 12, "g":{ "b": 2, "c": 4}, "d":5}
```

`tree_traverse(tree, "d")` should return 5

Here is my code:

```
def tree_traverse(tree, key):
    for k,v  in tree.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            tree_traverse(v, key)

        elif k == key:
            return v
```

The problem I have is that this function returns None if it doesnt find the matching key once it's done iterating through the deepest nested dict.
I don't want it to return anything before the matching key is found.

I didn't find a solution in another thread, most of them use print statements and don't return anything so I guess it avoids this issue.

Comment: Rather, you need to check the result of the recursive call to determine whether or not to return it.

Comment: I tried `return tree_traverse(v, key)` but same problem

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I thought the problem was there but how to implement this correctly ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check whether the recursive call actually found something so you can continue the loop. E.g. try the following:

```
def tree_traverse(tree, key):
    if key in tree:
        return tree[key]
    for v in filter(dict.__instancecheck__, tree.values()):
        if (found := tree_traverse(v, key)) is not None:  
            return found
```

Comment: wow, thanks that works. Wouldnt have figured out myself. Assigning the recursive function call to a variable and testing it before returning it. Awesome!

Comment: You are fast! Here is my working demo with the same solution: ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NCsIwEEbXySk@smqhCP5tCr2CV5DaTjVU05COgVI8e51UXAiuJo9v3szET3wb3H5ZOBChwmxqU2K7K2CuppxhLoKJGqmHlzxaUx5fWrfUITlnDnWkMFKWqEBPU15q1Q0BfYEI69a2jWV6jFmKlO3Qo6pSa0IViJ/BISoBuktqR@tGrl1DWSzQ2oZXT3k58Hdn/CxMoXheTLiBcRocrcZ3ttfaB@sY2b@b5U95vixv "Python 3 – Try It Online"))

Comment: @aloisdg 7 minutes for a reasonably simple find and short answer is usually too slow :D

Comment: @schwobaseggl I guess I need more practice :3

Answer (score 1):

Here we instantiate an object when the function is created, that all executions of the function will share, called `_marker`.  We return this object if we don't find the key.  (You could also use `None` here, but `None` is frequently a meaningful value.)

```
def tree_traverse(tree, key, *, _marker=object()):
    for k,v  in tree.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res = tree_traverse(v, key, _marker=_marker)
            if res is not _marker:
                return res
        elif k == key:
            return v
    return _marker

def find(tree, key):
    _marker = object()
    res = tree_traverse(tree, key, _marker=_marker)
    if res is _marker:
        raise KeyError("Key {} not found".format(key))
    return res
```

I use `tree_traverse` as a helper function because we want different behaviour at the outermost layer of our recursion (throw an error) than we want inside (return a `_marker` object)

Answer (score 0):

A `NestedDict` can solve the problem

```
from ndicts import NestedDict

def tree_traverse(tree, k):
    nd = NestedDict(tree)
    for key, value in nd.items():
        if k in key:
            return value
```

```
>>> tree = {"a": 12, "g":{ "b": 2, "c": 4}, "d":5}
>>> tree_traverse(tree, "d")
5
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`