# How to get an item from a dictionary which contains list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary which contains list of dicts:

```
dict = {"key0": "some_value", "key1": 1, "value": [{"key2": "some_value", "key3": "some_value", "key4": {"key5": 0}, "key6": {"key7": {"key8": "some_value", "id": "some_id"}, "key9": {"key10": "some_value", "id": "some_id_2"}}}]}
```

I am struggling to find a way to get 'id' field, in case I find that "key7" or "key9" exists. Something like:

```
for key in dict.items(): 
    if 'value' in dict.keys(): 
        if 'key7' in dict.values(): 
            print("I want to print key7 id value here")
```

Expected output:
`some_id`

Comment: does it always has same format

Comment: No, 'value' may have more complex structure, depending on the output, e.g more 'keyX' with subsets of 'keyY'.

Comment: is it always key7 and key9

Comment: use recursion, there's numerous answers out there that show how

Comment: `'key7' in dict.values()` is False, `'key7' in dict.keys()` is False, and `'key7' in dict.items()` is False. Also, `dict['value']` is a list, and `dict` is already a Python keyword. Maybe consider splitting up your dictionary into separate dictionaries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively iterate through a nested dict and return value of the first matching key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260624/recursively-iterate-through-a-nested-dict-and-return-value-of-the-first-matching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will come across this, found a way how items can be accessed:

```
my_dict = {"key0": "some_value", "key1": 1, "value": [{"key2": "some_value", "key3": "some_value", "key4": {"key5": 0}, "key6": {"key7": {"key8": "some_value", "id": "some_id"}, "key9": {"key10": "some_value", "id": "some_id_2"}}}]}
```

Then something like this:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items(): 
    if isinstance(v, list): 
        value_list = v 
        if not value_list: 
            pass 
        elif value_list is not None: 
            for vl in value_list: 
                print(vl['key6']['key7']['id']) 
                print(vl['key6']['key9']['id'])
```

It goes through dictionary, until the value of the dictionary is list, then if value is list, using list comprehension, you can access elements and it will output:

```
some_id
some_id_2
```